# What do U and R stand for in UIO, RIO, and URIO?

Tags: zio

ZIO provides these convenient aliases for common ZIO usages:

```
UIO[A]         // Equivalent to ZIO[Any, Nothing, A]
RIO[R, A]      // Equivalent to ZIO[R, Throwable, A]
URIO[R, A]     // Equivalent to ZIO[R, Nothing, A]
```

What do `U`, `R`, and `UR` stand for in these aliases? It seems like `R` is *maybe* a reference to the fact that the first type parameter of a ZIO is named R. Is that true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`U` stands for “unexceptional” as in it isn’t expected to produce exceptions in the error channel (thus the `Nothing` In the error channel of the underlying `ZIO`).

`R` stands for “Resource” or “Requirement”. I personally prefer to think of it as the latter because it fits better with my mental model of not being able to run an effect until all the requirements are satisfies.